# How to define an Apache Camel route to InfluxDB

Tags: java, apache-camel, influxdb

I want to send data to an InfluxDB using Apache Camel. I am at such a beginner's level, that I cannot even understand camel's documentation. I am struggling what exactly needs to be written in the `<route>` tag of the spring configuration XML. [In the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/influxdb-component.html) it says:

- URI format: `influxdb://beanName?[options]`
- The InfluxDB endpoint is configured using URI syntax: `influxdb:connectionBean`

How do I use this information? Could you provide me a more instructive example of how the config.xml looks like and how this is called in code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to configure a spring boot **InfluxDb** class instance and then reference it as stated in the documentation using *beanName*.

This can be created using spring boot auto configuration:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-influxdb
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/influx/InfluxDbAutoConfiguration.html

According to [Spring AnnotationNameGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html) the name of the default (from the yml auto configured bean) should simply be `influxDB`. We can also look at [the bean definition code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/influx/InfluxDbAutoConfiguration.java) and confirm it is creating an `InfluxDB` class instance.

So then configure `influxdb://influxDB` in camel.

---

Besides auto configuring this alternative should work too (untested - [source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-influxdb)):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean(name = "myInflux")
    public InfluxDb influxClient{
        return InfluxDBFactory.connect(databaseURL, userName, password);
    }
}
```

And then configure `influxdb://myInflux` in camel.